# read only particular json files from s3 buckets from multiple folders

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

am trying to scroll over all buckets in s3 and see if there is a prefix that matches and get into those folders and read the json files.

I have tried to get the folders that contain a prefix, but failing to enter them.

Code:

```
import boto3
bucket = ['test-eob', 'test-eob-images']
client = boto3.client('s3')
for i in bucket:
    result = client.list_objects(Bucket=i,Prefix = 'PROCESSED_BY/FILE_JSON', Delimiter='/')
    print(result)
```

Using this am getting the ones with prefix and fails when bucket doesnt have that prefix.

structure of `test-eob` , `test-eob/PROCESSED_BY/FILE_JSON/*.json` 
I have to read the json if only my prefix matches, else come out of the bucket.

Can anyone help me out here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to catch the error(is it a `KeyError`?) when the bucket does not contain the prefix.

For example:

```
for i in bucket:
    try:
          result = client.list_objects(Bucket=i,Prefix = 'PROCESSED_BY/FILE_JSON', Delimiter='/')
          print(result)
    except KeyError:
          pass
```

To read the **json**, there are several ways. For example with `json.loads()` from the json module.

So for each object in the bucket:

```
content_object = s3.Object(bucket_name, file_name)
file_content = content_object.get()['Body'].read().decode('utf-8')
json_content = json.loads(file_content)
```

Comment: So I have to insert the json code after the print(result) right ?

Comment: Yes, you have do this for each json object.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I will let you know if there is any difficulty.

Comment: hey so I have four kinds of jsons, named as `666-Account.json`, `77-Account.json`, `22-Multi.json` and so on... I only want to read *Account.json. How do i do that ?